# If statement being executed despite condition not being met

Tags: c++, if-statement

Ok, so, this is a bit of a weird issue to me. I have this portion of code in my program that uses an if statement to check and see if a page was found in memory, both of which are structs. However, I have an idea of what the output should be and my output is way off so I started checking through some areas to see where it could be coming from and in the process of doing that I ran into this issue. Here in this spot:

```
    if(memory.memory[i].uid==position)
    {
      i=pages;
      found=1; //The page was found in main memory
      cout << memory.memory[i].uid << " " << position << endl;
    }
```

The cout there is for testing purposes and is how I found this issue. The memory.memory[i].uid is always equal to 0, but the code inside the if statement runs anyway (so I get huge blocks of "0 ##" with ## increasing as it should be due to the position variable).

Is there any possible reason that would happen? It just doesn't make sense to me that the code inside the statement is being executed despite the statement being false. Both of the variables in the statement are integers.

(I'm not sure how much more of the code would be needed, it's a big program spanning 3 files so I didn't want to include all of it if I can avoid it. If more is needed though I can edit more in.)

EDIT: Wow, I'm blind. I just realized I'm modifying i before that statement so it's not the same i being used in the statement. After fixing it so the statement was before the modification of i the values are matching as they should be, sorry for the waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-assigning to `i` between the comparison and the printing can of course give the expression `memory.memory[i].uid` a different value. If you want to see the value that's used in the comparison, make sure you capture it *before* re-assigning to `i`.

Comment: You're right, I just noticed it right after I posted the question. I should have paid more attention, ha.

Comment: @JimmyDoyle Heh. It's the same principle as [rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging): merely attempting to explain the problem can give you new insights that you missed earlier. In this case it came shortly after posting the question, but you seem to be on the right track to having it happen before posting next time. :)